# Yii2 сохранение hasMany

Tags: php, yii2, relation

Есть таблица с записями(items) и таблица с категориями(categories)

Одна запись может находиться в нескольких категориях, т.е. получаем массив вида

```
$category_ids = [1, 2, 3 и т.д.];
```

Для этого имеется еще одна таблица(items_categories) вида

> item_id | category_id

Как правильно сохранять подобное ? Можно конечно пройти foreach как-то так

```
foreach( $category_ids as $category_id )
{
   $model = new itemsCategories();
   $model->item_id = $item->id;
   $model->category_id = $category_id;
   $model->save();
}
```

Но может кто подскажет более правильное решение ?

Comment: Делаете массив и далее делаете `batchInsert` http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#batchInsert()-detail  ......к тому же обычный `INSERT INTO` позволяет делать так:`VALUES(1..., 2...), VALUES(3..., 4...), VALUES(5..., 6...),.....` http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-insert-multiple-records/

Comment: Спасибо, batchInsert то что нужно. Правда не понятно, экранирует ли он автоматом все или нет, или проще через int прогнать для надежности ? Не совсем разобрался, достаточно ли правил в модели, вроде `['categoryIDs', 'each', 'rule' => ['integer']]`

Answer (score 0):

это делается при помощи https://github.com/voskobovich/yii2-many-to-many-behavior

полное описание здесь

http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2015/10/yii-2.html

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться методом ActiveRecord::link():

```php
$items->link('categories', $categories);
```

Однако для этого необходимо, чтобы у обеих моделей были правильно настроены методы связей:

1 В модели Item должен присутствовать метод

```php
public function getCategories(): ActiveQueryInterface
{
    return $this
        ->hasMany(Category::class, ['id' => 'category_id'])
        ->viaTable('items_categories', ['category_id' => 'id']);
}
```

2 В модели Category должен присутствовать метод

```php
public function getItems(): ActiveQueryInterface
{
    return $this
        ->hasMany(Category::class, ['id' => 'item_id'])
        ->viaTable('items_categories', ['item_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Подробнее про метод ActiveRecord::link() можно прочитать в [документации по Yii Framework](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/db-active-record#saving-relations)